# Divide distance between two dates into multiple one-month intervals

Tags: sql-server, date, t-sql

I have a table  like this :

| CustomerId | StartDate | EndDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-05-01 |
| 2 | 2022-03-01 | 2022-04-01 |

Now I want to have another table that for each CustomerId , each rows show one month Interval from StartDate To Enddate , For Example a table like this:

| CustomerId | EffectiveDate |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-01-01 |
| 1 | 2022-02-01 |
| 1 | 2022-03-01 |
| 1 | 2022-04-01 |
| 1 | 2022-05-01 |
| 2 | 2022-03-01 |
| 2 | 2022-04-01 |

How can i do this and Divide distance between startdate and enddate into one-month intervals date like above?

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (CustomerID INT, StartDate DATE, EndDate DATE)
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES (1,'2022-01-01','2022-05-01'),
(2,'2022-03-01',    '2022-04-01')
```

```
2 rows affected
```

```
WITH DateRangeCTE AS (
    SELECT CustomerId, StartDate, EndDate
    FROM MyTable
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CustomerId, DATEADD(MONTH, 1, StartDate), EndDate
    FROM DateRangeCTE
    WHERE DATEADD(MONTH, 1, StartDate) <= EndDate
)
SELECT CustomerId, StartDate AS EffectiveDate
FROM DateRangeCTE
ORDER BY CustomerId, StartDate;
```

| CustomerId | EffectiveDate |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-01-01 |
| 1 | 2022-02-01 |
| 1 | 2022-03-01 |
| 1 | 2022-04-01 |
| 1 | 2022-05-01 |
| 2 | 2022-03-01 |
| 2 | 2022-04-01 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/h1-bu8pU)

Comment: Thank You, If enddate was '2022-04-20' and  I want to have Enddate in last row , what should i do?

Comment: @nasim_bbb can you provide more information ?

Answer (score 1):

Just another option using an ad-hoc tally table

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([CustomerId] int,[StartDate] date,[EndDate] date)  
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 (1,'2022-01-01','2022-05-15')  -- Note EndDate
,(2,'2022-03-01','2022-04-01')
 
Select A.CustomerId
      ,NewValue = case when N<datediff(month,startdate,enddate)
                       then dateadd(month,n,startdate)
                       else enddate
                  end
 From @YourTable A
 Join (
        Select Top 500 N=-1+Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select NULL)) From master..spt_values n1, master..spt_values n2
      ) B
    on N<=datediff(month,StartDate,EndDate)
```

**Results**

```
CustomerId  NewValue
1           2022-01-01
1           2022-02-01
1           2022-03-01
1           2022-04-01
1           2022-05-15   << Note End Date
2           2022-03-01
2           2022-04-01
```